Why does AskFM archiver option to continue download not working as expected?
I am asking this question because the AskFM site shuts down at the end of the month and am having issues.
I've used askfm Archiver for backing my profile up, however it always end up with 500 server error somewhere in the progress (AskFm's servers are unstable, same on the website).
f:\ast>askfmarchiver.exe -u [username] -a
[03:25:06 INF] Application is Starting: Archival Service
885
Progress: 5,65%   [03:25:37 FTL] Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at askfmArchiver.Utils.NetworkManager.HttpRequest(String url)
   at askfmArchiver.Parser.GetHtmlDoc(String url)
   at askfmArchiver.Parser.GetNextPage(HtmlDocument html)
   at askfmArchiver.Parser.ParsePage(HtmlDocument html)
   at askfmArchiver.Parser.Parse()
[03:25:37 ERR] Attempting to commit 75 answers to the database.
[03:25:37 ERR] Successfully committed 75 answers to the database.

So I found out that, instead of removing everything and starting over from zero, you should be able to continue the download using -p option (-p for page)
I try to continue, starting from page 75:
f:\ast>askfmarchiver.exe -u [username] -a -p75
[03:25:43 INF] Application is Starting: Archival Service
810
[03:25:48 ERR] ParsePage(): articleNodes are null. html is:
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Progress: 100%   Finished Parsing 0 answers.
[03:25:48 INF] Application is Done: Archival Service

It inevitably ends here. What am I doing wrong?
